# Table layout affected by font in use

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-table

Apparently, Google’s Dosis font screws up table layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" />
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                width: 100%;
            }

            td {
                outline: 1px solid red;
            }

            #test {
                font-family: "Dosis";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="test">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="control">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above setting cells in the table on which Dosis is set have uneven spacing, while those in the one without a font family set are as expected.

What is suprising is that the incorrect behaviour is perfectly consistent across Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

Can anyone please explain this, and possibly give a solution?

Comment: Could you describe what "incorrect behavior" is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because the width of 1,2,3,4,5 are not the same, why do I think this? Try by using the same text:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" />
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                width: 100%;
            }

            td {
                outline: 2px solid red;
            }

            #test {
                  font-family: 'Dosis';

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="test">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="control">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>​​​​​​
```

You can use css to make the width of td tag fixed. Or javascript to make make the width dynamically allocated.